# How to declare multiple register variables in one line in c?

Tags: c, syntax

I'm implementing destroy method for a linked list by keeping pointers to previous and current nodes. I'd like to declare them as register variables in a single line. Is it possible?

```
void list_destroy(list *ls) {
  // does this mean both prev and curr are register variables?
  register node *prev, *curr;
  
  for (prev = 0, curr = ls; curr != 0; curr = curr->next) {
    if (prev != 0)
      free(prev);
    prev = curr;
  }
  free(ls);
}
```

or

```
void list_destroy(list *ls) {
  node register *prev, *curr;
  
  for (prev = 0, curr = ls; curr != 0; curr = curr->next) {
    if (prev != 0)
      free(prev);
    prev = curr;
  }
  free(ls);
}
```

Comment: Give up - write it in assembler.

Comment: For the most part, you should forget that `register` is a keyword in C — just like you never use `auto` either.  The compiler will make register assignments on it's own, better than you can, and it will largely if not completely ignore your use of the keyword.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Noted and thank you for your advice. I removed `register` from this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`register` is a storage class specifier, so it applies to all the declarators in the declaration.  It applies to bit `prev` and `curr` in these examples.

Commonly, you put storage class specifiers first on the line (before any type specifiers) but that is not required.  Storage class and type specifiers can be in any order (but all must be before the declarators and any pointers or qualifiers or other modifiers on the declarator)